# How to match password and confirm password with Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Use TextFormField widget which consists of a builtin validator

This code is only for valid without firebase validation but with firebase validation it can store data on database even both password and confirm Password cannot match?

Here I will give my code

```
void _submitForm() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    var date = DateTime.now().toString();
    var dateparse = DateTime.parse(date);
    var formattedDate = "${dateparse.day}-${dateparse.month}-${dateparse.year}";
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      try {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });

        await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _emailAddress.text, password: _passwordController.text);
        final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
        final _uid = user!.uid;
        user.reload();
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_uid).set({
          'id': _uid,
          'username': _username,
          'email': _emailAddress,
          'joinedAt': formattedDate,
          'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
          'Password': _passwordController.text,
        });
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignInPage()));
      } catch (error) {
        _globalMethods.authErrorHandle(error.toString(), context);
        print('error occured ${error.toString()}');
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

TextFormField of both Password and Confirm Password

```
Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 42),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      key: const ValueKey('Password'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid Password';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        icon: Image(
                          image:
                              AssetImage('assets/images/Icon feather-lock.png'),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                      ),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _passwordController.text = value!;
                      },
                      onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context)
                          .requestFocus(_confirmPasswordFocusNode),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 42),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _confirmPasswordController,
                        key: const ValueKey('Password'),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                            return 'Please enter a valid Password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        focusNode: _confirmPasswordFocusNode,
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        onEditingComplete: _submitForm,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                          icon: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/Icon feather-lock.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          _confirmPasswordController.text = value!;
                        }),
                  ),
```

Comment: Where is your code that actually sends the password to firebase? If you don't show it we can't see how the logic of your validator and Firebase interaction are connected.

Comment: I added but due restriction it cannot upload

Comment: I think everyone should be allowed to [edit]?

Comment: Ok finally I can edit Now please check and solve my issue.

Comment: Are you checking that the value in the repeat-password validator is the same as _passwordController.text?

Comment: Yes , I check. Both are same

Comment: It can store data on database. it doesn't matter value are match or not

Answer (score 0):

Use this to match your `password` and `conformPassword`

```
if (conformPassword != password) {
      return 'password is not matched'
    }
```

Comment: I use it and it works. 
Dialoge appear "Password is not matched" But it can store data on database.